# Django model object query misbehaving

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset, django-orm

I am trying to display the contents of a profile which is a model that is linked to the inbuilt User model. Everything works fine, strangely except the last object entry of the model. For example if user8 is the last model object logging in with user1 to user 7 is working with all the contents inside verified belonging to the current user. but when I login using the last object ie. user8 in this case I get a Page 404 not found : No (Model name) matches the given query error. to be bit more clear, now if I create another user called user9 , Now I am able to login with user8 but not with the lastly created user9.

**views.py : **

```
# Create your views here.
def home(request):
    

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        contextvar = Post.objects.all()
        user_content = get_object_or_404(user_profile, pk = request.user.pk)
        
        # user_content = user_profile.objects.get(pk=request.user.pk)
        # user_content = user_profile.objects.get(pk='8')
        print("the current users id is " , request.user.pk)
        return render(request,'homepage.htm', {'context':contextvar , 'user_content' : user_content ,  "up" : request.user.pk })
        
    else:
        contextvar = Post.objects.all()
        return render(request,'homepage.htm', {'context':contextvar})
```

**models.py :**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
# Create your models here.
class user_profile(models.Model): 
    #using default User model by linking 
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    #additional fields
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pictures' , blank = True )
    bio = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=300)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return (self.user.username + " " +  str(self.user.id))
```

**Page error :**

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/
Raised by:  blog.views.home
No user_profile matches the given query.

You're seeing this error because you have DEBUG = True in your Django settings file. Change that to False, and Django will display a standard 404 page.
```

Please let me know if you need to see anything else... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It shouldn't behave properly, because you are querying user profile with user's primary key. To be honest, you do not need it, because you can get the user profile by:

```
user_profile = request.user.user_profile
```

Due to [OneToOne](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.OneToOneField) relation between `User` and `user_profile` model.

FYI, class names should be PascalCase as per [pep-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).